# How to use <i18n-t> in Web component?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-i18n

I'm creating a Vue web component using i18n
And I wanna put a span tag with color in 
here is my code demo.
I wanna know how to import

```
<!-- custom-element.ce.vue -->
<script setup>
import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n'
const { t } = useI18n()
const locale = ref('en')
defineProps({
  locale: String,
})
</script>
<template>
<div classs="custom-ele-wrap">
    <i18n-t keypath="title" tag="span">
        <template #text>
             <span :class="['locale-text', locale']"> {{ localeText }} </span>
        </template>
    </i18n-t>
</div>
</template>
<style scoped>
.locale-text.en {
    color: blue;
}
.local-text.zh-TW {
    color: red;
}
</style>
```

```json
// <!-- i18n json -->
{
    "en": {
        "title": "{text} language",
    },
    "zh-TW": {
        "title": "這是{text}語言",
    }

}
```

but it shows
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smPh6.png)

Comment: In your template you can use `<span>{{ t('title') }}</span>` instead of the i18n-t tag.

Comment: @Gabe thanks for your reply. But I want to put a slot in <i18n>

Comment: Can’t you import `i18n-t` from useI18n like you do with `t`?

Comment: I have tried it in one of my projects and the `i18n-t` component gets imported automatically…

Answer (score 1):

There are two questions here:

1. How to import the `i18n-t` component without it being globally injected, like it is when you use `vue-i18n` as a plugin?
2. How can I use [Component Interpolation](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/advanced/component.html) with Web Components and `vue-i18n`.

For the first question you can import `Translation` from `vue-i18n` and use that in place of the `i18n-t` component:

```
import { useI18n, Translation } from 'vue-i18n'
...
<Translation keypath="title" tag="span">
```

But unfortunately that doesn't help with the second question.

You can't use [scoped slots](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/web-components.html#slots) with Custom Elements